# Installing Eclipse plugins through cli takes 10 minutes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-neon

I'm installing some Eclipse (Neon) plugins with the cli on Ubuntu 16.04. E.g.:

`eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon -installIUs org.eclipse.team.svn.revision.graph.feature.group`

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  
Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Installing org.eclipse.team.svn.revision.graph.feature.group 4.0.0.I20160226-1700.
Operation completed in 497738 ms.
```

I wonder why this takes so long and what the "state location" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Taking so long

The Eclipse download servers were very slow this morning. [New download servers](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499399#c30) are currently being provisioned to hopefully resolve the regular [Tuesday morning slowdown](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=498116) (in short, every Eclipse installation by default connects Tuesday morning at 10am to check for updates).

### State Location

That is another way of saying workspace. Obviously you don't need a workspace for running that application, but it looks like org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration is being over cautious with its warnings. I believe it is trying to set some setting for logging from your workspace settings, but because there is no workspace (state location) it fails and you get that info message.